# maintain Menu Item selected state

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

i have a menu in my asp.net page.the menuitem and url are loading dynamically from code behind during 
`IsPostBack=false`.

After i clicked on any of the menu item, the selected item background color was changed and after directing to another url, the selected state was cleared.

i tried the code below and it does not work.The css class was not applied to the item after postback

```
  Dim s2 As String = Request.QueryString("sub")
    For Each item As MenuItem In Menu1.Items
        If item.Text = s2 Then
            item.Selected = True              
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
  <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" role="tablist" Orientation="Horizontal"  CssClass="nav nav-pills"  ForeColor="Black" RenderingMode="List" IncludeStyleBlock="False">
                     <%-- <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="Focus" />--%>
                     <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="nav nav-pills"/>
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="MainNavStyle"/>
                        <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="active"/>
                 </asp:Menu>
```

html mark up after selected. the active class was there. but disappeared after postback or page load

```
<div role="tablist" class="nav nav-pills" id="ctl00_Menu1" style="float: left;">
<ul class="level1 nav nav-pills static" tabindex="0" role="menubar" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
<li role="menuitem" class="static active" style="position: relative; float: left;">
```

please take note that the control menu is at master page and the data are loaded from master page as well

Comment: please add your webform code as well

Comment: thanks. already added my webform code

Comment: "the active class was there. but disappeared after postback or page load" is key I think > don't know how to do this in VB, but test for Page.IsPostback.

Comment: when i debug it step by step in chrome. after i clicked the menuItem. before it direct to next page.the active class was added.
after directing to next page.the class disappeared.

Comment: i think this article pointed out whats going on to menu item.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1338691.aspx?menu+selected+item+css

but the solution does not work on me